# Does execlp get blocked until there is data available in FD?

Tags: c, pipe, dup

This is a correction for an assignment I got, the assignment is the emulate the command `who|grep` in a C program. When I tested it, it worked as expected.

From my knowledge, when fork is called, the two processes (child and parent) run in the same time simultaneously, what I don't understand, what makes the commands get executed in the right order, is it necessary to have data available in the pipe `FD` so `execlp('wc', 'wc', NULL)` get executed? Will it be blocked till data is received from the son process ?

```
int fd[2], n;
if(pipe(fd) == -1){
    perror("Pipe creation failed");
    exit(1);
}
n = fork();
if(n == -1){
    perror("Fork error");
    exit(2);
}
else if(n == 0){ //son
    close(1);
    dup(fd[1]);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    execlp("who", "who", NULL);
}else{
    close(0);
    dup(fd[0]);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    execlp("wc", "wc", NULL);
}
```

---

From what I found in `man 7 pipe` section **I/O on pipes and FIFOs** :

> If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will block until data is available.  If a process attempts to write to a full pipe (see  below),  then write(2)  blocks  until sufficient data has been read from the pipe to allow the write to complete.  Nonblocking I/O is possible by using the fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation to enable the O_NONBLOCK open file status flag.

Does this apply still on functions like execlp that gets input from `FD`

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: @kaylum can you tell me then please, what's making this not execute as expected: https://pastebin.com/1Z9Hb2c1 I used the same logic as the first one, but apparently the `WC` is not getting any input from `grep`. Ps: in this one, I'm trying to replicated the command `ps -aux | grep root | wc -l`

Comment: `execlp` doesn't read anything from an open file, and doesn't wait. However, _this_ `execlp` runs the program `wc` with no arguments other than the standard `argv[0]` -- and _that program_ reads its standard input aka fd 0, which is (the read side of) the pipe, and thus blocks. Also in C (and C++) `'x'` is a character literal and more than one character is nonportable while `"xyz"` is a string literal and can be multiple characters. (This differs from shells, perl, php, and python, where both `'` and `"` can be used for strings.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for tips, can you put it in an answer so I can mark it as answered. And if you can, can you check the code I shared in the previous comment, thanks!